# Powershell console not executing cmdkey to save password so the mstsc asks for login/pass

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, mstsc

I want to login to windows remote desktop via simple script which

1. saves the password (so I do not see the prompt dialog asking for credentials)
2. opens the remote desktop

I have written and save it as a `.bat` file:

```
cmdkey /generic:"Wk123" /user:"myLogin" /pass:"myPassword"
mstsc /v:Wk123
```

After I run it, the remote desktop opens without asking for credentials.

But If I save given script as `.ps1` and run it in powershell, the login/pass dialogs opens and I am still beeing asked to enter the password. The dialog says: "The logon attempt  failed".

Result from running the command is the same:

```
CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
```

Why same commands work in a `.bat` file but does not in `.ps1` ?

Comment: Try adding the full SPN for the RDS endpoint: `cmdkey /generic:"TERMSRV/wk123" /user:...`

Comment: how can I find what the SPN is?

Comment: `setspn -l wk123`. The SPN for the Remote Desktop service will have the prefix `TERMSRV`, so it'll likely be either `TERMSRV/wk123` or `TERMSRV/wk123.fqdn`

Comment: I tried both TERMSRV/wk123 and TERMSRV/wk123.my.domain but neither worked.